# Accessing gitlab inside docker container from local machine

Tags: docker, centos, gitlab

I am trying to set up gitlab inside a docker container, where my docker container is running on a remote CentOS 7 server. Apparently, gitlab is running just fine because I can access the container and perform wget and also from the server. However, I cannot do the wget from my local machine. I would like to configure it so that I can access from anywhere, but I have no idea how to do this configuration or what it's missing.

I created the docker container like this:

> sudo docker run --detach --hostname gitlab.example.com --publish 18080:80 --publish 12222:22 --publish 1443:443 --name gitlab --restart always --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest

just as the official documentation http://doc.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#after-starting-a-container was saying.

I would like to access via http://public_ip:18080. How can I achieve that?

I already tried opening port 18080 in CentOS:

> $ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=18080/tcp --permanent
>
> $ sudo firewall-cmd --reload

but it's not working (and I don't really know what I'm doing here).

The container is running and the command

> docker ps -a

shows this:

> 88510679f781        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest    "/assets/wrapper"        About an hour ago   Up About an hour                 0.0.0.0:12222->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1443->443/tcp         gitlab

I can access the webpage from inside the server and from different machines inside the same cluster using the private ip of my server and port 18080. However, I cannot access with the preconfigured public ip of the server.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the replies, the issue was that the firewall was not letting us listen on every port. Changing the mapping to an available port made the trick

Comment: First, the obvious questions: is your container actually running (e.g., are you sure it didn't just exit)?  Can you access gitlab using the container's ip address (on port 8080)?

Comment: It is running, now I can access the webpage just fine from inside the server and even from different machines in the same cluster using the private ip of that machine + port 18080. However, access through the public ip is not working.

Comment: Does your server cluster by any chance have its own firewall?

Comment: In case you're running the server in Amazon, make sure your security group allows communication on port 18080

Comment: @warmoverflow It has its own firewall, indeed. I am logged in, so I was assuming I wouldn't have any more problems.

Comment: @warmoverflow You were right, we investigated the firewall and it wasn't letting us listen on every port. Changing the mapping to the available open ports made the trick